# create trigger in nodejs mysql2 without using sequalize

Tags: node.js, database, express, triggers, mysql2

i am trying to create trigger with mysql2,express and nodejs  in my database and is there a way to create trigger in database table without sequalize ,delimiter is not working

```
        var sqlBeforeUpdateTrigger=`CREATE TRIGGER  beforeSupplierUpdate
        BEFORE UPDATE ON Supplier
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SupplierUpdate
        SET action = 'update',
        supplierId=old.supplierId,
        name=old.name,
        email=old.email,
        country=old.country,
        state=old.state,
        city=old.city,
        street=old.street,
        pinCode=old.pinCode,
        poBox=old.poBox,
        supplierDetails=old.supplierDetails,
        updatedOn= NOW();
        END;`;

    
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
       
            db.query(sqlBeforeUpdateTrigger, function (err, result, fields) {
               if (err) {
                  reject(err);
               }
              resolve(result);
             });
             
           });
```

Comment: what does it mean it's not working? Is your promise never resolved? Or do you get some specific error?

Comment: it says parse error but when i run the same query in workbench it works

Comment: please, paste here the entire error message

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter $$
  CREATE TRIGGER  beforeSupplierUpdate
  BEFORE UPDATE ON Supplier
' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is delimiter is only supported by mysql client provided by workbench or some other softwares inorder to run procedures where we have to seperate instruction instead of delimiter we can join different instruction using javascript + operator to get sql query string i.e

```
var sqlQueryTrigger='CREATE TRIGGER beforeSupplierUpdate'+
  ' BEFORE UPDATE ON Supplier' +
  ' FOR EACH ROW' +
     ' BEGIN' +
  ' INSERT INTO SupplierUpdate'+
  'SETaction="update",supplierId=old.supplierId,name=old.name,
  email=old.email,country=old.country,state=old.state,
  city=old.city,street=old.street,
  pinCode=old.pinCode,poBox=old.poBox,
  supplierDetails=old.supplierDetails,
  updatedOn= NOW();' +
 'END;';

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
   
        db.query(sqlBeforeUpdateTrigger, function (err, result, fields) {
           if (err) {
              reject(err);
           }
          resolve(result);
         });
         
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

for starters, your query is invalid. You're mixing the INSERT and UPDATE statements. When you do an update, the general syntax looks like `UPDATE table_name SET column=value`, but that's not the case when you insert. The syntax for that is `INSERT table_name (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (val_for_column1, val_for_column2, val_for_column3)`

Comment: i am not just inserting value or updating into table i am just creating a trigger which is trigerred on every update on supplier table